# I'm seeing a lot of 500s in rails log from potential threats, how do I auto identify and block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache

I'm seeing a lot of 500 errors in Rails to routes like

```
"ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/SQLiteManager/main.php"):"
```

and variations of this. Obviously bots trying to find a way to login to something.

Is there a fail2ban type gem for rails or something in apache to block these clients or IPs?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to block IP addresses in application level, you can handle it in application_controller with a simple before_filter as below

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :authorize_request

  protected

  def authorize_request
    head :unauthorized if blocked_ip_addresses.include?(request_address)
  end

  def request_address
    request.env['HTTP_X_REAL_IP'] || request.env['REMOTE_ADDR']
  end

  def blocked_ip_addresses
    $redis.smembers('blocked_ip_address')
  end   
end
```

You can add suspicious IP addresses to your redis on the go juts by doing

```
$redis.sadd('blocked_ip_address','XX.XX.XX.XX')
```

If you are not using redis, you can keep the list in array and update it manually, which would require application restart/deploy.